# Why if $e$ is independent to $\hat y$, then $\hat\beta $ will be independent of $S^2$.

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

$\bullet$ $X$ is a matrix $n\times p$,

$\bullet$ $y=X\beta +\varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon\sim\mathcal N(0,\sigma ^2I_{n\times n})$

$\bullet$ $\hat \beta=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$

$\bullet$ $\hat y=X\hat\beta =Hy$

$\bullet$ $H=X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$

$\bullet$ $S^2=\frac{e^Te}{n-p}$

$\bullet$ $e=y-\hat y$.

In a proof of my course, it's written : *"Since $e$ and $\hat y$ are independents, then $S^2$ and $\hat \beta $ are also independents"*.

**So, why do we have this implication ?**

Comment: Ok, so it's the only reason. It was my first thought. Thanks.

Comment: @Clarinetist I don't think this is the right reasoning, or at the least, I can't show why this argument is valid. One can come up with a counterexample where these aren't necessarily independent.

Comment: For example, you could have a case where $Y$ and $X_2$ were independent but $Y$ and $X$ are not.

Let $Y=2X$ and $X=\pm 1$ with equal probabilities. Then $X_2=1$ a.s. and independent of $Y$. However, $Y$ depends on $X$.

Comment: @Glassjawed Wow, two years ago! And yes, you're completely right. Deleted my comment. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/173402/46427.